# django broken thumbnails

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, broken-image

I am trying to make a blog with an imagefield for my posts. I have imageupload working in the django admin panel but I have broken thumbnails. If I click on the images I got a 404 error with the following:

```
Using the URLconf defined in firstblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='home']
^admin/

The current URL, images/heroimage/, didn't match any of these.
```

in my models.py I have:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink


class posts(models.Model):

author = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
bodytext = models.TextField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/heroimage/", default='')
category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category', default='')


def __unicode__(self):
 return '%s' % self.title

@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
 return ('view_blog_post', None, { 'slug': self.slug })



class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)


def __unicode__(self):
 return '%s' % self.title

@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
 return ('view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

What I'm trying to do is to have the image that was uploaded to the post, displayed on the site.

Here is my index.html where I try to call the image to the post.

```
  <div class="container">
        <h1>First Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="posts">
        <p><a href="/images/heroimage/{{blog.slug}}"> <img src="{{blog.image1.url}}" /> {{ blog }}</a></p>
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <h3>Posted on {{ post.timestamp }} by {{ post.author }}</h3>
        <p> {{ post.bodytext }}</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

my django project I created was called firstblog , I then have an app named blog. In the root of my project folder "firstblog" I have a folder for images and then a sub folder inside that one called heroimage.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Try to rename {{blog.image1.url}} to {{ post.image1.url }} in index.html, since image1 is a field of Posts.

Comment: And you should rename posts to Posts. Classnames are always written with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

It is appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Set a media root for uploaded files the to retrieve the files, ill give you an example:

```
# settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# models
class Blog(models.Model):
    main_image = models.ImageField(default='none/none.jpg', upload_to='blog'

# template
<img src="/media/{{ blog.main_image }}">

# media folder after
media/blog/imageuploaded.jpg
media/none/none.jpg  # This file was already created
```

To upload to the static directory change

```
MEDIA_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT or STATICFILES_DIRS[0]
```

Though this is absolutely not recommended!